# Magento 2 REST API returns Error

Tags: rest-api, magento-2.2.5

I have made REST API callout to get products based filter criteria. Following is the endpoint. `http://xxxxxxxx/magentodemo/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_g‌​roups][0][filters][0‌​][field]=updated_at& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2018-08-24 08:35:37&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]‌​=eq`. I got response as below.

```
{"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5b9f70d36a6c1"}.
```

I have gone through log file to check the Error Details.

```
[2018-09-17 09:16:03] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5b9f70d36a6c1;Message: Invalid URI supplied {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5b9f70d36a6c1;Message: Invalid URI supplied at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\magentodemo\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Webapi\\ErrorProcessor.php:205,Zend_Uri_Exception(code: 0): Invalid URI supplied at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\magentodemo\\vendor\\magento\\zendframework1\\library\\Zend\\Uri\\Http.php:156)"} []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead, i think you have to encode the date, you have problem in the endpoint

> /V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2018-08-24%2008%3A35%3A37&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue so i erased the var/cache folder contents and also the var/session folder content. Then refresh page and that should do it.

Comment: I don't find any session folder in var. I have deleted folder contents in cache.

Comment: Flush Your Cache then check it should work.

Comment: @SalesforceElearner Does it Work?

Comment: It doesn't work but I have seen strange thing through mozilla firefox i'm getting above metioned error. when it comes to Google chrome it gives me Invalid Signature. Without filtercriteria it is working in both browsers.

Comment: Yes it could be browser specific issue .May be issue with your browser cache and cookies but the above solution work for me in every browser.

Comment: I got this Error. "message":"Invalid signature"

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, if the endpoint is

```
rest/V1/invoices/6
```

I receive all the data of the invoice.
If the endpoint is

```
rest/V1/invoices/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2018-09-18%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt
```

I receive the error message: **Invalid signature**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Encode the url. your issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return any error from restAPI Dont use \Exception it will not be shown as json if you are in **production mode**, It will work in development mode only, Implement Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException and then even in production mode you will get the proper response in json format.